# cropped cropped but not maintaining the aspect ratio

Tags: php, jquery, image, crop, jcrop

i am cropping images, images are cropped fine but after i view the cropped image, it crop image from some random places and i dont know why this is happening. I am following this post http://mrbool.com/jquery-crop-cropping-images-with-jcrop/26243

```
       <form id="crop_form" action="crop.php" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
                                <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="src" id="src"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="original_width" id="original_width" value="<?php echo $row['width']; ?>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="original_height" id="original_height" value="<?php echo $row['height']; ?>"/>
                                <a id="image_crop" name="image_crop" >
                                    <img src="images/icon-01.png" width="41" height="41"  alt="" />
                                </a>
                            </form>

                        </div> 
                        <?php
                            $width = $row['width'];  
                            $height = $row['height'];
                        ?>
                        <img title="" id="main_image" src="<?php echo "patternimages/" . $row['img_name'] ?>" width="<?php echo $width; ?>" height="<?php echo $height; ?>"> </div>
```

following is my JS code

```
  $(function() {

        var main_image_src = jQuery('#main_image').attr('src');
        jQuery('#src').val(main_image_src);
        jQuery('#image_crop').on('click', function() {
//            checkCoords();
            jQuery('#crop_form').submit();
        });

        $('#main_image').Jcrop({
            aspectRatio: 1,
            onSelect: updateCoords,
        });

    });

    function updateCoords(c)
    {
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    }
```

And here is `Crop.php`

```
<?php

session_start();
$targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
$jpeg_quality = 90;

$src = $_POST['src'];
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor($targ_w, $targ_h);

imagecopyresampled($dst_r, $img_r, 0, 0, $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $targ_w, $targ_h, $_POST['w'], $_POST['h']);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r, 'dummy.jpg', $jpeg_quality);

exit;
```

Comment: is your target width and height the same aspect ratio as the original?

Comment: if you see the newly created image that i create in crop.php i am not setting any aspect ratio, so i assume its same, if its not can you advise me on how to make it same

Comment: you will have to do some math, as you are specifying a target width and target height, the width / height is the aspect ratio... (as your target with and height are the same, your making a square.. so any image you process which isn't square will be distorted) To be honest, I would suggest looking at Imagick library, as its a bit better for what you need to do.